# Endpoints and custom middleware cause exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a custom middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            await context.Response
            .WriteAsync($"Before \n");
            await next();
            await context.Response
            .WriteAsync($"After \n"); 
        });
```

and endpoint:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

The problem is that it throws an exception:

*An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.*

but when my middleware looks like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            await next();
            await context.Response
            .WriteAsync($"After \n"); 
        });
```

everything works just fine. Why the response can only be modified in the Return Pipeline.

And when im using `endpoints.Map.Get`instead of `endpoints.MapControllerRoute` like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context => { 
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
```

Everything works just fine in both cases. I know it can be a silly question but I wanted to ask why I can't modify response before it is passed through the pipeline when I use `endpoints.MapControllerRoute`? It says that the response has already started so why it is possible to modify it only in the return path but not when the request is processed? Shouldn't it be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Once you write something to the body, the HTTP headers are finalized and no more headers can be written. However, on your `await next()` call, a middleware built into the MVC pipeline attempts to write headers and fails. When you directly use `MapGet` instead, there is no other middleware that is executed, and therefore no attempt to write to the headers once they've been finalized, and so your code executes property.

Comment: Can you explain it more thoroughly?
**Once you write something to the body**
You mean writing with `await context.Response.WriteAsync($"After \n"); `?
**When you directly use MapGet instead, there is no other middleware that is executed**
What do you mean by that. Isn't it the same with `endpoints.MapControllerRoute`?

Comment: Yeah, a HTTP response is made up of a header and body, and the body is the actual content (the headers store metadata like cookies). Since the header comes first, in order to transmit anything in the body you have to mark the end of the header. endpoints.MapControllerRoute means that in addition to your custom middleware, requests will also go through several built-in middleware such as MVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-middleware